# SoftLayer API call to trunk vlan fails

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The following api call does not return an error and appears to work, but the vlan does not actually get trunked.  Instead we have to manually reach out to SoftLayer and have them trunk the vlan to the specified devices.

This is the api call, in Python, although it should be similar in other languages:

```
client['Network_Component'].addNetworkVlanTrunks([{'id': 121212}], id=565656)
```

Sadly, SoftLayer was unable to research or address this at all via their internal ticketing system.  Instead they told us to post the issue here, as this is apparently where their "api experts" hang out.

Does anyone have insight they can share related to this api call?

Answer (score 0):

The api call that you are using to add the networkVlanTrunks works fine.

If you want to check if the **vlan trunks were added successfully**, you should check the **Uplink Component** and its **networkVlanTrunks**, as says in this link: [SoftLayer_Network_Component::addNetworkVlanTrunks](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Component/addNetworkVlanTrunks)

Try the following python script for it:

```
"""
This script Retrieve the network component linking this object to parent and
their network vlan trunks

See below references for more details.
Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Component/getUplinkComponent
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

@License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
@Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer username and apiKey
user = 'set me'
api = 'set me'

# Connect to SoftLayer
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=user, api_key=api)

# Define the network component Id
networkComponentId = 916616

# Define an object mask to get network vlan trunks
mask = 'mask[networkVlanTrunks]'

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Network_Component'].getUplinkComponent(mask=mask, id=networkComponentId)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

I did some tests and I verified that the vlan trunks were added successfully.

I hope it helps.
Please, let me know any doubt or comment about it.

Comment: Thanks Ruber.   But what I am saying is that the API call marks the VLAN as trunked, and reports it is trunked, when in fact the trunking never occurred.  We verified this by testing traffic, then seeing that VRRP adverts were not being received, and then by reaching out to SL, who after some troubleshooting realized the VLAN was not actually trunked, and had to trunk it manually - which defeats the purpose of automation via API.

We opened a ticket with SoftLayer, and were told to ask here (where their api experts are) and our ticket was closed.   So what's the next step towards resolution?

Comment: As I know, the configuration for the vlan trunks is done over layer 3. If you want to test the vlan, apparently you need to configure this in the layer 1 (Configure your server for the vlan trunk), if you need more assistance with this or have any doubt about it, please submit a ticket to softlayer (Network). Attach this forum if is necessary.

Comment: I understand.  Our server was properly configured, but as I said the trunking was not performed.  That is the issue, and that is the part that nobody seems willing to actually test.  Saying it works, and that the system says it did the trunking is not the same as testing it.  In our production clusters when trunking is not done things are broken.  How can I get someone from SoftLayer to make the api call, and manually verify the trunking is operational?

Comment: You should submit a ticket to SoftLayer, the networking team will help to check this. Attach this forum to the ticket, if the support team recommends you to post here.